# How check if a variable is a date, string or float (numeric) [PHP]

Tags: php

Hy guys, i have a problem.

My variable can have different values in my cycle:

- values="10"
- values="Hello"
- values="2015-02-17"

How do I check the type of variable with a condition? I have tried but string type is "equal" to date type.

Comment: you can use functions like is_int(), is_float() or is_string()

Comment: if you have values="2015-02-17" and values="Hello" and i use if(is_string($values){ echo "have string" } else echo " have date" this don't work's because values is taken for string and not for date

Comment: Both `"2015-02-17"` and `"Hello"` are strings ... are you expecting something different? Technically even `"10"` would be a string as it's in `"` marks.

Comment: Yes,sorry for my title is incomplete. if i have values=Hello or values=2015-02-17  values=10, something changes?

Comment: The only way that `"2015-02-17"` would be a date is if you made it one in the first place with something like `new DateTime('2015-02-17')` (which would be a `DateTime` object) ... otherwise it *is* just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the php `gettype()` function to find the type

Comment: My problem is that, I can not distinguish the date from the string.

Comment: you can try `strtotime()`  function which will convert to a time stamp  so that you can distinguish date and string

Comment: I used a shortcut with strtotime(), It's not nice but it works :). Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of built-in functions in PHP, mainly beginning with `is_`

- `is_a` is_a — Checks if the object is of this class or has this class as one of its parents
- `is_array` — Finds whether a variable is an array
- `is_binary` — Finds whether a variable is a native binary string
- `is_bool` — Finds out whether a variable is a boolean
- `is_buffer` — Finds whether a variable is a native unicode or binary string
- `is_callable` — Verify that the contents of a variable can be called as a function
- `is_dir` — Tells whether the filename is a directory
- `is_double` — Alias of is_float()
- `is_executable` — Tells whether the filename is executable
- `is_file` — Tells whether the filename is a regular file
- `is_finite` — Finds whether a value is a legal finite number
- `is_infinite` — Finds whether a value is infinite
- `is_int` — Find whether the type of a variable is integer
- `is_link` — Tells whether the filename is a symbolic link
- `is_nan` — Finds whether a value is not a number
- `is_null` — Finds whether a variable is NULL
- `is_numeric` — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string
- `is_object` — Finds whether a variable is an object
- `is_readable` — Tells whether a file exists and is readable
- `is_resource` — Finds whether a variable is a resource
- `is_scalar` — Finds whether a variable is a scalar

There are a few others - some are aliases of some mentioned here - others not. The PHP manual will offer far more information on each but they can be used to form the backbone of a logical test for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky but you could so something like:

```
function dataType($data) {

    // is_numeric() will validate ints and floats
    if(is_numeric($data)) return "number";

    // if $data is not a valid date format strtotime() will return false
    // so we're just using it as a validator basically
    elseif(strtotime($data)) return "date";

    // is_string() does what you'd expect
    elseif(is_string($data)) return "string";

    // anything else that you're not looking for
    else return "other";

}

echo dataType("Hello"); // outputs "string"
```

There would be issues with `is_numeric()` however if your numbers use `,` separators in any way, for instance NL number formating `1,5` or UK formatting with thousand separators `1,000,000`.

You could get around this with the `number_format()` function if that's the case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: ok, but if you have values="10" with " " don't have different with string and numeric. With Value=10 without " " have only numeric