# strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object for timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently trying to compare two dates to determine the difference. The data is pulled out from mysql server. However, I keep on getting this error:

> strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

I have tried going through the some of the steps that people have tired before but it doesn't work.

```
$qa_date= new DateTime ($row["fa_timestamp"]);
$sale_date=new DateTime ($row["time_enter"]);
$timestamp1 = strtotime($qa_date);

$timestamp2 = strtotime($sale_date);

$weekend = array(0, 6);

if(in_array(date("w", $timestamp1), $weekend) || in_array(date("w", $timestamp2), $weekend))
{                                       
    return 0;
}                                       
$diff = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;                                       
$one_day = 60 * 60 * 24; //number of seconds in the day                                     
if($diff < $one_day)
{
    return floor($diff / 3600);
}

$days_between = floor($diff / $one_day);
$remove_days  = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= $days_between; $i++)
{
   $next_day = $timestamp1 + ($i * $one_day);
   if(in_array(date("w", $next_day), $weekend))
   {
      $remove_days++; 
   }
}

$diff2= floor(($diff - ($remove_days * $one_day)) / 3600);
```

Comment: $qa_date is not a string - `$qa_date= new DateTime ($row["fa_timestamp"]);
$timestamp1 = strtotime($qa_date);` Seems, you want `$timestamp1 = strtotime($row["fa_timestamp"]);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44725268/2943403

Comment: Seems your strtotime($qa_date); or strtotime($sale_date) is empty thats why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a conversion method in the DateTime class, so you can replace strtotime() by this

```
$timestamp1 = $qa_date->getTimestamp();
$timestamp2 = $sale_date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: I tried using this the error is gone but now my screen is blank